# how to store this kind of value in database

Tags: php, sql, database, store

I have a sql database ,I need to store values coming referral url's into it.The problem is each member of my company uploads a file,in order to get statistics in this case `referrals` is becoming very difficult.Should I create table for every user with 200 columns and then add the referrals?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't understand what you need to store into your database. If it is what i think it is, you can use 1 single table with 200 columns (no ideea what you want to store into 200 cols), for each of your users assign an ID. In each row add the ID of your user.

Comment: basically I want to make a structure showing effeciency as well as ligibility...if several refferal entries are created is there a better way of storing data?

Comment: The answer below does the thing that i spoken earlier. But is more explicit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table `referrals` and save the referrals against the `user Ids`.Here `userid` will be foreign key.

for e.g:

```
ID      UserID         Referrals

1        32            referrals link here
2        41            referrals link here
```

and so on. So in this way you can easily keep track the count of `referrals` for each user.

As per your comment, if a `user(abc)` having id `32` got too many referrals then only your rows will increase

for e.g:

```
ID      UserID         Referrals

1        32            referrals link here 1
2        32           referrals link here 2
3        32            referrals link here 3 
4        32           referrals link here  4
```

Now you can see the user id is repeating but the value of `Referrals` changes.This is a far better way of getting your approach rather than creating 100's of columns.

Comment: actually the refferals are coming from several websites eg facebook,gplus,youtube ... around 100 of them... in which case what may I do? I could add colums for new entries in a table but if a single user has around 200+ referrals all others will have empty colums..

Comment: NO I have suggested you to make one table for `referrals` in which your rows will increase only not columns.see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your data. You want it in one table for all the users and while there are potentailly some tables that might require 200 columns, they are exceptionally rare.

In databases, you generally (not always, but most of the time) want to add more rows of data and contain less columns.

As a quick example, lets say you need to store sales by day, and that your sales data comes in once per week. You don't want to create a table with columns for MondaySales, TuesdaySales and so on, you create a table with a date that is the date of the sales transaction. There isn't anything that you can't run a query against daily data that could be done on a weekly table and it really makes queries and analysis MUCH easier.

In this case, if you want to add a column to minitor a referral, you can do it by either adding a single column to the table, or if you have the possibility that you get multiple referrals for each row of data, you probably want to create another table just for referrals that links to your staff.

Comment: but if over time 17000 files are created then 17000 tables need to be created..do you think it would be wise to group them user-wise?

Comment: @user2754528 No, you put all the files into the ONE table. You mark the user in it, but you put all the records into the same table.